# Pandas not plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Unable to plot

```py
byDate = df.groupby(['Date'],axis = 0).count()
byDate['lat'].plot
```

I have already tried to use plt.show()

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from plotly import __version__
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.read_csv('911.csv')
df.set_index('twp')
df['reason'] = df['title'].str.split(':').str.get(0)
df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'])
df['Hour'] = df['timeStamp'].dt.hour
df['Month'] = df['timeStamp'].dt.month
df['Day of Week'] = df['timeStamp'].dt.weekday_name
df['Date'] = df['timeStamp'].dt.to_period('M')

byDate = df.groupby(['Date'],axis = 0).count()
byDate['lat'].plot

byDate = df.groupby(['Date'],axis = 0).count()

Out[50]: pandas.plotting._core.SeriesPlotMethods object at 0x000001DB6105C400
```

Sample data for the plot

```
Date        lat 
2015-12-10  114 
2015-12-11  391 
2015-12-12  402 
2015-12-13  316 
2015-12-14  444 
2015-12-15  419 
2015-12-16  376 
2015-12-17  387
```

Comment: Date lat
2015-12-10 114
2015-12-11 391
2015-12-12 402
2015-12-13 316
2015-12-14 444
2015-12-15 419
2015-12-16 376
2015-12-17 387

Comment: That is a sample of the data

Comment: If you want to add sample data please edit your question and add it there, comments are not the right place for sample data

Comment: `plot` is a function in the pandad DataFrame, not a variable.  Have you tried with rounded brackets like `byDate['lat'].plot()`?

Comment: Awesome Hoog, you are a genius! it was that.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment Hoog did the .plot part needs the brackets like ".plot()"